# How sort in expression Lambda when a linked class is nothing

Tags: vb.net, sorting, lambda

I use a method to filter or sort dynamically an array.
And Sometimes, a column in not directly in the objet but in a linked class.
For example, I create a array of article and a article have a supplier.
To sort I use this function

```
 Public Function CallOrderedQueryable(Of T)(query As IQueryable(Of T), methodName As String, propertyName As String) As IOrderedQueryable(Of T)
    Dim param = Expression.Parameter(GetType(T), "x")
    Dim Compar As Int64?
    Dim body As Expression = param
    Dim Parentbody As Expression = Nothing
    If propertyName.Contains("?") Then '? sépare Recherche/Tri sur flag
        Compar = CInt(propertyName.Split("?")(1))
        propertyName = propertyName.Split("?")(0)
    End If
    For Each member In propertyName.Split(".")
        Parentbody = body
        body = Expression.PropertyOrField(body, member)
    Next
    Dim condPart As Expression
    If (body.Type.FullName.Contains("Int32") OrElse body.Type.FullName.Contains("Int64")) AndAlso Compar IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim toDouble As Expression = Expression.Convert(body, GetType(Int64))
        Dim Flag As Expression = Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(Compar), GetType(Int64))
        condPart = Expression.Equal(Expression.And(toDouble, Flag), Flag)
    ElseIf Parentbody IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim s0 As Expression = Expression.Equal(Parentbody, Expression.Constant(Nothing, Parentbody.Type))
        If body.Type.FullName.Contains("String") Then
            condPart = Expression.IfThenElse(s0, Expression.Constant(String.Empty, GetType(String)), body)
        Else
            condPart = body
        End If
    Else
        condPart = body
    End If
    Return query.Provider.CreateQuery(Of T)(
    Expression.Call(
        GetType(Queryable), methodName,
        New Type() {GetType(T), condPart.Type},
        query.Expression, Expression.Lambda(condPart, param)))
End Function
```

And I use in my class a property
<TableFullOption.TFOProp( "Article.Supplier.Name")> Property IdFournisseur As Integer?
The problem is when Supplier is nothing
Cause Supplier.Name give an error message about null object ...
Then I Check if ParentBody is not nothing but I've error message saying Type Void can't bu used

> Le type 'System.Void' ne peut pas être utilisé comme argument de type.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

In the end ... replace Expression.ifthenelse by expression.Condition